# how to read List<Serializable> XML element

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have below inner class in my original class which is generated by JAXB (converted xsd to java classes). I want to know how to access the value of element associated with name ="a" below java client? 
I tried to create java bean and replaced List with my List but when use getA() method, it gives me `ClassCastException:` can't cast String to MyJavaBean Object.

please help me how to read below XMLElementRefs in java client code which is trying to use this class and read the XMLdata.

```
public static class sfdsfs{

            @XmlElementRefs({
                @XmlElementRef(name = "a", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "b", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "c", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "d", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "e", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "f", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "g", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "h", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "i", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
                @XmlElementRef(name = "j", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)

            })
            @XmlMixed
            protected List<Serializable> content;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
            protected String name;
```

Comment: look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/mgrebac/entry/handling_extended_mixed_content_in) and [here](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_12_7-Mixed-Content.html) Maybe help you.